# Issue with Alt or Ctrl key codes in forms

Tags: jquery, keycode

Key combinations such as `Alt + 0233` gives é. In my online forms, I want to use `Alt + e` or `Ctrl + e` instead to generate é. I know how to do this with jQuery but the issue is `Alt + e` is also associated with edit menu of the browser and hence opens up the menu. Similarly `Ctrl + e` is also associated with some other browser functionality. Using `Ctrl + ' + e` also gives the same result.

I want to know if there is a workaround for this problem. Has anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get what you need by trapping the keystrokes and processing:

```
$('#scanned_element').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 101) {
        if (e.altKey) {
            /* Alt-e was pressed here  (code 101 = 'e')*/
            ...
            /* Stop event from bubbling */
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Also you may want to check out Jquery Hotkeys (https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)

Comment: If you were going to do this, you'd also probably want to call `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` to stop the event from bubbling out to the browser.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi yes, I think that does the trick. I totally forgot about `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Guys, would you also know how to use `Ctrl + ' + e` to do something like above. I tried `if (e.which == 101 && e.which == 39 && e.ctrlKey)` but it does not seem to work. See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hzLwC/

Comment: `e.which` is only ever one value per call to that function, so `e.which == 101 && e.which == 39` will never be true.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi I was testing the script in different browsers and found out that `e.preventDefault()` only seems to work in Firefox and not in other browsers. I tried http://jsfiddle.net/hzLwC/ in IE, Chrome, etc - doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: @shortstuffsushi I made changes to code to stop the bubbling.  I hadn't thought about that.  Good catch.

Comment: @user1448031 I'm not terribly familiar with the differences between browsers, but you could be right. When I looked at the fiddle, it was working for me. However, keypress doesn't seem to catch alt events correctly. You may instead need to try with keydown, in which case the keycode/which values will be slightly different (69 w/ ctrl, 229 w/ alt). http://jsfiddle.net/Fq4Zu/